# Synchronizing Events

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I noticed that sometimes my code becomes out of sync if an event fires too quickly.  I was wondering if there was a better approach. Under a normal scenario the DeviceOpenedEvent fires after I tell the thread to WaitOne in the TestDevice method, but I have seen in some cases where the event gets fired before the thread has a chance to wait.

```
    protected AutoResetEvent TestAutoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public EventEnum WaitForEvent = EventEnum.None;

    bool TestDevice()
    {
        OpenDevice();

        WaitForEvent = EventEnum.DeviceOpened;
        TestAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        WaitForEvent = EventEnum.NoWait;

        //Continue with other tests
    }

    void DeviceOpenedEvent()
    {
        if (WaitForEvent == EventEnum.DeviceOpened)         
            TestAutoResetEvent.Set();                           
    }
```

Under normal circumstances it looks like this:

1. Open Device
2. WaitOne()
3. DeviceOpenedEvent occurs
4. Set()

This is what I'm seeing my logs sometimes:

1. Open Device
2. DeviceOpenedEvent occurs
3. WaitOne() Essentially stuck here forever

Comment: Shouldn't the `OpenDevice` method dictate when the device has opened (not the `TestDevice` method)?

Comment: OpenDevice is an asynchronous method call.  TestDevice performs a bunch of operations on the device, like opening, locking, power on, powering off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `OpenDevice` is asynchronous (as you mentioned in a comment), it runs in a different thread than its caller. Sometimes it will finish before the next line in source executes:

```
    OpenDevice(); // Async: may finish before the next line executes!
    WaitForEvent = EventEnum.DeviceOpened;
```

When that happens `DeviceOpenedEvent` doesn't do what you want it to, because `WaitForEvent` is still `EventEnum.None`:

```
if (WaitForEvent == EventEnum.DeviceOpened)         
    TestAutoResetEvent.Set();
```

The solution is to change your code so that you signal completion inside a method that's guaranteed to run in the correct order. Here's a simple implementation that removes the enumeration and uses a single wait handle for each event you need to wait on:

```
protected AutoResetEvent deviceOpenedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
protected AutoResetEvent deviceLockedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

bool TestDevice() {
    OpenDevice();
    // Do some unrelated parallel stuff here ... then
    deviceOpenedEvent.WaitOne();
    LockDevice();
    deviceLockedEvent.WaitOne();
}

void DeviceOpenedEvent() {
    deviceOpenedEvent.Set();                           
}
```

It's even easier if you control `OpenDevice`: just call `deviceOpened.Set()` when it's done. You could even change `OpenDevice` to accept the auto reset event and construct it right inside `TestDevice`, which would reduce your exposure to multithreading bugs.

Comment: How is this scenario not possible?  1. OpenDevice() 2. Async callback 3. deviceOpenedEvent.WaitOne()

Comment: That scenario is possible, but it isn't a problem. When it happens, `deviceOpenedEvent.WaitOne` won't block (as Fredrik explained in his answer), because the `AutoResetEvent` stays signaled until something 'consumes' it. Unless there's another thread waiting on the event, it's fine (and you can work around *that* by using a `ManualResetEvent` or another signaling mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45zkwyy6.aspx) for `AutoResetEvent` states:

> If a thread calls WaitOne while the
>   AutoResetEvent is in the signaled
>   state, the thread does not block.

The following code does not cause `WaitOne` to block, for instance:

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
waitHandle.Set();
waitHandle.WaitOne();
Console.WriteLine("After WaitOne");
```

Comment: It won't block - unless there's another thread waiting on the same event, in which case the other thread will consume the signal and the event will be reset. @Robert, is something like that going on here?

Comment: @Robert: with that update it sounds as if the situation that @Jeff describes might be valid. Is there any other code using `WaitOne` to wait for signals in the same `AutoResetEvent` instance?

Comment: @Fredrick - I think we both missed the actual problem here: the wait handle is *never signaled*, because `OpenDevice` (and the `DeviceOpenedEvent` method) completes before the next line of code executes.